# Why do my VBA code sometimes work and most of the times it doesn't?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub UpdateCSAH()
Dim S As String
Dim R As Long
Dim RR As Long
Dim CC As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim csah() As String 'an array that stores the CSAH sites
ReDim csah(1 To 100, 1 To 7)
Dim Ran As Range
Dim Ran1 As Range
Set Ran = Worksheets("Current Sites").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'Ran is the region that has values
RR = 1 'row number in csah
CC = 1 'column number in csah

'check each value in Ran to see if its Route section has "CSAH"
For Each cell In Ran
    R = cell.row
    S = CStr(Cells(R, 4).value)
    If InStr(S, "CSAH") > 0 Then 'check if "CSAH" is in the Route section
        If CC > 7 Then 'reset the column number and go to the next row when reach the end of the column
            CC = 1
            RR = RR + 1
        End If
        csah(RR, CC) = cell.value
        CC = CC + 1
    End If
Next cell

Worksheets("CSAH Sites").Select
Range("A2:G100").Select
Selection.ClearContents

'assign each array values to cells in sheet"CSAH Sites"
i = 1
j = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(csah, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(csah, 2)
        Cells(i + 1, j) = csah(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

'format the CSAH Sites values
Set Ran1 = Worksheets("CSAH Sites").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For Each cell In Ran1
    If cell.row = 1 Then
        With cell.Font
            .Color = -11489280
        End With
    ElseIf cell.row Mod 2 = 0 Then
        With cell.Interior
            .Color = 10092441
        End With
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

I have an Excel worksheet named "Current Sites" that has some data. If the 4th column has the word "CSAH", I want to store the values of that row into an array and assign those values to cells in the worksheet named "CSAH Sites". My code sometimes works (the 1st time you click), and most of times it doesn't work or doesn't work properly.

Please help me out! Thanks A Bunch!!

Comment: Downvoted due to the formatting of the source code in the example. Please make sure you double check your content before posting. It makes it extremely difficult to determine what your source is actually doing.

Comment: How does it not work properly? Does it always fail on a certain line of code? In the middle of your code you have `Cells(i + 1, j) = csah(i, j)` but we have no way of knowing to which worksheet and workbook the `Cells` belong. Please add the worksheet and workbook qualifiers to this line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to check every row of data in the "Current Sites" sheet and if column 4 includes the "CSAH" text, then write the first 7 columns of data for that entry to the "CSAH Sites" sheet and add some colour to the even-numbered rows.

To check every row of data, you can read down just one column and use either the `Offset` or the `Cells` method to see the values of neighbouring cells. In your code you were "touching" every cell and each time you were then looking at the value in column 4 and also checking to see if the code had gone past column 7. That slows things down a lot and makes the code hard to understand.

You can also assign the values from a range of cells directly to another range of cells without using variables or an array.

See if this does what you want:

```
Sub UpdateCSAH()

Dim currentSitesRange As Range
Dim thisSiteRange As Range
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim numRowsOfData As Long

Const NUM_COLUMNS_OF_DATA As Integer = 7

    Set currentSitesRange = Worksheets("Current Sites").Range("A1")
    numRowsOfData = currentSitesRange.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Set currentSitesRange = currentSitesRange.Resize(RowSize:=numRowsOfData) 'currentSitesRange is the region that has values

    Worksheets("CSAH Sites").Range("A2:G100").ClearContents

    Set outputCell = Worksheets("CSAH Sites").Range("A2")

    For Each thisSiteRange In currentSitesRange.Cells
        ' Look for "CSAH" in the Route section (column D)
        If InStr(1, thisSiteRange.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value, "CSAH", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Found "CSAH" so write NUM_COLUMNS_OF_DATA columns of data to CSAH Sites sheet
            outputCell.Resize(ColumnSize:=NUM_COLUMNS_OF_DATA).Value = thisSiteRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=NUM_COLUMNS_OF_DATA).Value
            ' Format the even-numbered rows
            If outputCell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                With outputCell.Resize(ColumnSize:=NUM_COLUMNS_OF_DATA).Interior
                    .Color = 10092441
                End With
            End If
            Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        End If
    Next thisSiteRange

End Sub
```